# AngularJS and hard beginnings - simple app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am studying AngularJS and met the problem with my, actually, hello world app.
At first I will show the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nazwa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "#">Add Order</a>
<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var mainModule = angular.module("nazwa", []);

mainModule.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'customerController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/View1.html'
        })
        .when('/cos', {
            controller: 'customerController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/View2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);


mainModule.controller('customerController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        {name: 'john', lastname: 'dersky'},
        {name: 'someone', lastname: 'lastname'},
        {name: 'peter', lastname: 'dewski'}
    ];

    $scope.addCust = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
            {name: $scope.newCust.name, lastname: $scope.newCust.lastname}
        )
    }
});
```

View1.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"/><br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name">{{cust}}</li>
    </ul>

    <br/>
    Customer Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCust.name"/><br/>
    Customer Lastname:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCust.lastname"/><br/>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add</button>
    <br/>
    <a href="#/cos">View 2</a>
</div>
```

And View2.html is pretty the same, but few changes

And the problem is that when I run index.html nothing shows. Even if I add some {{1+2}} code to index.html, the browser shows raw "{{1+2}}" rather than "3".
When I comment whole routing (mainModule.config) then {{1+2}} works fine and shows 3, but index.html still show neither View1 nor View2

What causes the problem? I have searched whole web, for hours and nothing.. what a shame

thanks for you help and dont beat me too hard for my mistakes, I am quite new in Angular :)

edit:
I found the console log errors:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2e5qgeh.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dfsq mentioned you are most likely missing ngRoute module. It is [available for download here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/angular-route.min.js).

Include that in your project before `app.js` as well as the code changes that dfsq mentioned.

Comment: thank you so much! it is the answer :) although another problem is that when I press "Add" button to add new customer, then nothing happens, what can be the problem?

Comment: @azalut you didn't connect your button to the function in your scope. Add ng-click="addCust()" to your Add Order link

Comment: omg such a stupid mistake.. though experience in programming still making such a mistakes :) thank you doubly

Comment: @azalut No problem! Feel free to mark my answer as correct if you'd like to repay me :P

Comment: here you go ;)I was following the video-tutorial on youtube and the autor didnt have to include any angular-route JS file, strange.. maybe it depends on angularjs version?

Comment: @azalut Yes it depends on the version. Newer versions of angular no longer include angular-route out of the box its in a different file now

Comment: hard to figure it out when you are completely new in it, but I suppose I will enjoy AngularJS when I get more familiar with it, cause now I do :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to add ngRoute module dependency:

```
var mainModule = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

By the way open a console (F12) and check for errors: there must be one saying that.

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work, any other ideas? I found the errors in console, pic is upper

Comment: Are you really posting complete code? Because error states that there something else except ngRoute error.

Comment: yup, the files I posted are ctr+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v :) I had only changed mainModule name from "nazwa" to "myApp" but now it is changed again to "nazwa" (read the code in my question once more)

Comment: @azalut Its not enough to just add ['ngRoute'] to your angular module. You need to actually download the js for ngRoute and include that on your page

Comment: @JesseCarter Damn, totally true! Missed that :) Thank you for valuable note!